# How to implement 2D torus without branches

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I need to implement a 2D torus for a CUDA kernel so it should be, if possible, with no branches.

E.g.

```
  |  |  |
--0--1--2--
--3--4--5--
--6--7--8--
  |  |  |
```

So thread 0 should know his neighbors are 1, 3, 6 and 2; and so on.

I get the right and left neighbors as follows:

```
right = (id + 1) % columns + firstRowId
left  = (id - 1) % columns + firstRowId
```

But I don't know how to get efficiently the upper and lower ids.

UPDATE: firstRowId means the id of the first element of its row, bad name, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these should do the trick:

```
n = rows * columns;
up = (id - columns + n) % n;
down = (id + columns) % n;
```

Comment: With firstRowId I mean the first id of its row but anyway I think it works ignoring your firstRowId. I'll test, thanks!

Comment: @rxp90 - Got it. That's what I originally had, so now it's back to that. :)